# How to get hidden data from a website in java

Tags: java, web-scraping

I developing a software in java and I want to get some text from a website. The problem is that it is shown in the browser and hidden when I got though code.

update:
I am reading through InputStreamReader from a website the comments field is not shown it is also not shown in the source code of the page.
When I open  that page in the browser the comments field is there and publicly available.

update:
The URL is http://www.alarabiya.net/articles/2011/07/20/158410.html

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

Exactly which comments are you not seeing? The following code gets the comments as far as I can tell:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.alarabiya.net/articles/2011/07/20/158410.html");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[8192];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1) {
    System.out.print(new String(data, 0, length));
}
in.close();
urlConnection.disconnect();
```

Note: the above code isn't production grade--just an example.

Comment: The code that you gave doesn't solve the problem. I still didn't get the comments. Thank you for your try. Regards

Comment: @Nayef: Which comments? As indicated in my answer, I ran this code and saw the comments just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response the just copy this string and try to find it in the result "في اخر المقال كتب هناك تسائل ان كان هناك مصلحه للثوره تحويل معركته مع النظام لحرب طائفيه" if it is not there it means the comments are not there as well, Regards

Comment: @Nayef: I don't find that string in the source of the web page, either. Can you give me a line number in the source?

Comment: There is no comments in the source code, they actually appear in the page only.

Comment: In the future, you might want to be more explicit about what you're looking for. When you say "comments", we think of HTML comments that are in the source but don't appear on a web page. You're talking about comments that users have left about the article. You're correct. They're not part of the HTML that's returned by that URL. They're requested asynchronously after that page loads. You can get them by requesting the same URL, whatever it is. Firebug or another HTTP monitoring app will show you the requests being made so you can track it down.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a blog post](http://blog.codehangover.com/read-html-with-java-then-7-fun-things-to-do-to-it/) describing how to get HTML from a url using the Java SDK, or Apache Commons HttpClient. Once you get the HTML, there is lots you can do to it.

1. Extract the Text from the Markup
2. Extract Links
3. Change Links
4. Collect Email Addresses
5. Collect Images
6. Add Syntax Highlighting
7. Diff Two Sources

[READ HTML WITH JAVA – THEN 7 FUN THINGS TO DO TO IT](http://blog.codehangover.com/read-html-with-java-then-7-fun-things-to-do-to-it/)

Comment: Disclosure, I wrote that a  couple years ago.